Picard Iteration Problem
Let $X: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$, $Y: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^e$ and $V: \mathbb{R}^e \rightarrow L(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^e)$ where $L(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^e)$ is the linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^d$ into $\mathbb{R}^e$. We want to solve the following DE:
$dY_t = V(Y_t)dX_t$ with $Y_0 =y$.
Provided that all the paths are nice and smooth, we can use Picard iterations to solve for $Y$ in the following way:
Look for a fixed point of $F(Y)_t = y + \int^t_a V(Y_s)dX_s$. Use the iterations $Y^n_t = F(Y^{n-1})_t$.
Then according we should get:
$Y^0_t = y$
$Y^1_t = y + \int^t_a V(y) dX_s = y + V(y)(X_t - X_a)$
But according to my notes we actually get
$Y^1_t = (\int^t_a dV(X_s) + I_e)(y)$ where $I_e$ is the identity operator in $L(\mathbb{R}^e, \mathbb{R}^e)$.
Could someone please explain how to get this / what this is saying?
Thanks
